# Set options to FbTransaction

Tags: c#, .net, transactions, firebird, firebird-.net-provider

How I can set this options to FbTransaction

```
write
nowait
rec_version
read_committed
```

in my code to execute insert/update sql statements:

```
FbConnectionStringBuilder fbConnStr = new FbConnectionStringBuilder();

using (FbConnection fbConn = new FbConnection(fbConnStr))
{
   fbConn.Open();
   using (FbTransaction fbTran = fbConn.BeginTransaction())
   {
      using (FbCommand fbCmd = new FbCommand("insert into TEST values (1)", fbConn, fbTran)
      {
         fbCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
         fbCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         fbCmd.Transaction.Commit();
      }
   }
   fbConn.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `FbTransactionOptions`:

```
FbTransaction transaction = Connection.BeginTransaction(
    FbTransactionOptions.ReadCommitted  |
    FbTransactionOptions.Write|
    FbTransactionOptions.RecVersion|
    FbTransactionOptions.NoWait |
    );
```

Look also at `IsolationLevel`:

- `IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted`
- `IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted`
- `IsolationLevel.RepeatableRead`
- `IsolationLevel.Serializable`

You could do:

```
FbTransaction transaction = Connection.BeginTransaction( IsolationLevel.Serializable );
```